# Is there a way to know when another hwnd has closed?

Tags: winapi, hwnd

Is there a method for setting up a listener/watcher to know when an unrelated application window is closed?

I can check to see if the window is still open, but that seems silly to continually do.

Comment: If the other app is not yours, you may need a system wide CBT hook.

Comment: Yes you're correct, it's not my application. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Accessibility API's [`SetWinEventHook`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) filtering for `EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY`.

This is notification based so no polling and unlike a CBT hook does not require injection.

Comment: Thank you, this is the simple answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can:

1. poll for `HWND` validity (esp. if you don't need timing precision)
2. subclass the window to intercept its `WM_DESTROY` and then forward the notification to your app
3. install a window message hook to be able to intercept the message otherwise
4. create a hidden child window to get it destroyed with the parent destruction, to also have your message handler called on time for you

Comment: I should have said it is an external application, I just need to know when it closes, but I cannot edit it.

Comment: Like any other handle type, `HWND`s get reused. Checking the validity of a `HWND` does not answer the question whether a window that had a particular `HWND` at the time of retrieval is still alive.

Comment: @IInspectable: It is a good point and in fact polling is not a reliable solution. Still API to check `HWND` value validity is here, it is simple and straightforward, and then sometimes one can accept the chance of mistake and prefer simplicity.